# How to retrieve the list of supported file formats for Matplotlib savefig() function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The [documentation of `savefig()` function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) says that the list of supported file formats depends on the used backend. How can I get this list of supported image formats for a specific backend?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to ask the `canvas`:

```
plt.gcf().canvas.get_supported_filetypes()
```

or

```
plt.gcf().canvas.get_supported_filetypes_grouped()
```

[documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.get_supported_filetypes)

Comment: From the "documention" link:                filetypes = {'ps': 'Postscript', 'eps': 'Encapsulated Postscript', 'pdf': 'Portable Document Format', 'pgf': 'PGF code for LaTeX', 'png': 'Portable Network Graphics', 'raw': 'Raw RGBA bitmap', 'rgba': 'Raw RGBA bitmap', 'svg': 'Scalable Vector Graphics', 'svgz': 'Scalable Vector Graphics', 'jpg': 'Joint Photographic Experts Group', 'jpeg': 'Joint Photographic Experts Group', 'tif': 'Tagged Image File Format', 'tiff': 'Tagged Image File Format'}¶