# Get list of supported file formats without opening a new matplotlib window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to use the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007248/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-supported-file-formats-for-matplotlib-savefig-func) question to provide a user with a list of supported file formats in the description of an `argparse` commandline option. However, this requires to run `plt.gcf()` which will open a matplotlib window. I would like to suppress this and just get the dictionary from `plt.gcf().canvas.get_supported_filetypes()` without opening the window. Is it possible to prevent `plt.gcf()` from opening a new window?

Code:

```py
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

options = str(list(plt.gcf().canvas.get_supported_filetypes().keys()))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-ext',help='Specify the file type. Options: {}'.format(options))
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: `print(options)` doesn't open any window when I run it.

Comment: `matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.get_supported_filetypes()`

Comment: Probably because you need to add a ```plt.show()```. I'm guessing using a plt.something implicitly creates a figure and an axes and when you use plt.show() all figure instances are opened in seperate windows. My full script has a plt.show() at the end.